# Emoji not saved correctly in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, utf-8, emoji

I am saving emoji from twitter and instagram into my mongodb database.
But when i display the pulled data from the database.
The emoji appear broken like this ❤️����������☀️��

Is there something i need to do different during saving data to mongodb, i am new to mongodb.
I have read the emoji's use utf8-mb4 encoding but mongodb support only UTF8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UTF8 is the default encoding supported by MongoDB  and support all characters (variable byte length) including utf8-mb4 (see below for further details). You are probably not converting your data to UTF-8 before uploading it to MongoDB or you are not treating the data as UTF-8 when retrieving the data.

Just to clarify, the original implementation "utf8" by MySQL was only for up to 3 bytes whereas the MySQL implementation called 'utf8-mb4' is actually up to 4 bytes long (like the official RFC recommends it).So utf8-mb4 in MySQL is the same as UTF8 in MongoDB.

Comment: Hi Jaco, i checked in database and the emoji are being stored correctly now but still when they appear on the web page the emoji appear broken.

Comment: i have even added <meta charset="utf-8"> in html head but still they appear broken.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from MongoDB ?

Comment: Hi Jaco, sorry for replying so late, i'm retrieving data using the query Content.where(_where_content(type)).order_by(:content=>:desc).limit(@page_size[type.to_sym]).to_a 
Which i later convert to a hash form and display using js.

Comment: @Yati - Have you figured out how to do this yet?

Comment: yeah its working for me now, the question mark are are gone and i'm able to seen the icons.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 in mongodb naturally supports emoji expressions