# Check string contains symbol questionmark"?" in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, twitter4j

Am using Twitter4j library to read the twitter text/tweet, more on info about it is [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html)

Now I want to find if the tweet contains "?" in it. Am reading the text using

```
status.getText()
```

It says it returns a string, hence I tried using string.contains but somehow it doesn't work just for the "?". If I use contains to find "http" in it, it returns me true but for this "?" it doesn't always. Sample tweet is as below

I'll hit you up when I get the ps4 though ??

Someone please help me on this.

Comment: what is the string value when you say `status.getText()`?

Comment: the one I showed as sample "I'll hit you up when I get the ps4 though ??". When I use contains function to check "http" in it, it works fine.

Comment: when you say `status.getText().contains("http")` it returns `true`? It  should not return true if that is all the text.

Comment: I mean for a different text where it has "http" in it. example like dgold8's Live PS4 Broadcast: https://t.co/gQc3D63VWU via @YouTube

Comment: So, are those actually question marks? Or are those your system trying to interpret emojis?

Comment: ahh yes could be emojis, how shall I confirm that?

Comment: You need to configure your code to compile on UTF-8 (and the screen to print on UTF-8), how you do that it depends on what are you using (OS, IDE, etc..)

Comment: Wow, that worked, compiling as UTF-8. So now in my MongoDB I see tweets sotred with emojis                                                                            e.g. "text" : "@thoughtofdallas I have an iPhone 6s"  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now can you please help me on reading out properly from MongoDB with emojis as right now when I read from MongoDB, still displays as ? instead of an actual emoji

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035050/emoji-not-saved-correctly-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

How about `string.indexOf('?') >= 0`?